# App to sync local folder with Amazon S3 service storage?

Tags: data-synchronization

I have an account with Amazon S3 service storage. I also have the Transmit app which allow me to sync any local folder with Amazon S3. It works fine but I want this to be done in a scheduled way (let's say every day at 10PM). As far a I see Transmit can not do this.

I try with Automator + Calendar. I works, but in this way you don't get any notification if the sync fails.

Looking for something similar to Chronosync app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highly recommend [Arc](http://www.haystacksoftware.com/arq/). Automatic backups from the menubar to A3, whatever and whenever you want.

Comment: I'm trying it. I does the job. Just a question, as far as see Arc encrypts the files. So, if I access my S3 storage account using a FTP app I can't see the files (because they are encrypted) Am I right? Can I make Arq not to encrypt the files, I mean, just to upload the files? Thanks

Comment: Also, is there any way to preview a remote file before I restore it?

Comment: I restore to the desktop so I can check it out before replacing a file.

Comment: I think it would be nice to have a preview by just clicking in the file. Anyway I see that Arq is best app so far to sync with S3 storage service.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what Jungle Disk does.

https://www.jungledisk.com/personal/